# Transfer Data from MySQL to Elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, kibana

I develop website with PHP, thus working with MySQL as database storage engine. For analyzing purpose I would like to use Kibana (web based analytics and search dashboard). There are two questions I would like to ask.

1. Is it possible to connect Kibana to MySQL? I only used to work with Elasticsearch and Kibana.
2. If Kiban must work with Elasticsearch. Is there any way to transfer data from MySQL to Elasitcsearch?

Comment: http://blog.randywallace.com/blog/2013/08/27/pulling-a-large-mysql-table-into-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

Kibana only works with Elasticsearch - so you'll need to copy your data across to Elasticsearch.

You could try the [river](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/) service or else use triggers in MySQL to create posts into Elasticsearch.